# Error creating silverlight 4.0 project for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

Trying to create a new project in VS2010 (on Windows 7 64-bit) of type **Windows Phone Application**, I get the error:

> You need to install the Silverlight 4.0 SDK before creating a Silverlight for Windows Phone project.
>   Download the Silverlight 4.0 SDK from: [link omitted]

If I try to install Silverlight 4.0 SDK, I get:

> A newer version of Microsoft Silverlight 4 SDK is already installed.

I have completely uninstalled and resintalled VS2010 (and SP1 service pack) as well as everything related to silverlight and WP7 SDK.

Comment: Nope. After uninstall/reinstall in that order, still same. I may try again...

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall everything that has to do with Visual Studio, Silverlight, and XNA. Then redownload everything and it'll work.

[Silverlight 4 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=7335) 
[Silverlight 5 SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229326) 
[Silverlight 5 Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229318) 
[Silverlight 5 Developer RuneTime x64](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229324) 
[Silverlight 5 Developer RuneTime x86](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229323) 
[Silverlight for WP7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=41&srcfamilyid=0a373422-6680-46a7-89e1-e9a468a14259&srcdisplaylang=en&u=http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/E/7/6E795194-EE2D-4636-AEBD-D1C42D2E06E1/vm_web2.exe) 
[Windows Phone Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=41&srcfamilyid=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&srcdisplaylang=en&u=http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/7/7/177D6AF8-17FA-40E7-AB53-00B7CED31729/vm_web.exe) 
[Also make sure you have Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691)

Comment: What are you suggesting here? Or just linking to every silverlight download