# How do convert a Silverlight 5 RC application into a Silverlight 5 application?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, runtime-error

I've been working on a Silverlight 5 RC project so far. After the official release of Silverlight 5 I installed the Silverlight 5 Tools and tested the application on another PC. The Silverlight plug-in gives me the following message:

> This application was created for an expired beta release of Silverlight. Please contact the owner of this application and have them upgrade their application using an official release of Silverlight.

It works fine in my development environment. The project settings target Silverlight 5. I use a library compiled for Silverlight 4 or 5 RC. The Silverlight plug-in on the other PC is up-to-date (Silverlight 5 not 5 RC). I searched the project files and setting but found nothing explicitly pointing to or depending on Silverlight 5 RC. I have no reason to think that the application is actually compiled as a Silverlight 5 RC application.

What could cause this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you got to do is download Silverlight 5 official release and rebuild your project.
[Here is a link to my previous post with all the Silverlight 5 download links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903229/error-creating-silverlight-4-0-project-for-windows-phone/8903721#8903721)

Comment: I forgot to rebuild the project. Thanks.